# UI terminology, and implementation for "marked" scrollbars

Tags: javascript, user-interface, scrollbar

I'm not sure what it's called in the UI vocabulary.

I have a (potentially long) document in a web browser. When the user searches for a term, I'd like to put colored hash marks on the scrollbar to show the relative positions of any matches within the document.

Google Chrome does this when you do a "find" text on a page, for example, but I'd like to do it against element classes.

So, two questions:

1. What's the proper term for this UI artifact that I could search for it?
2. Is there a jQuery implementation for such a thing already?

Comment: It's sometimes called a "Marker Bar" - but I don't know jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Pete; Looking for marker bars, I found [jquery.scrollmarker](https://github.com/sj26/jquery.scrollmarkers), which might be close enough, and might be better than what I was thinking to begin with.